# Listbox style selection does not work with datatemplate

Tags: wpf, listbox

I am using a ListBox and a ListBox style from here: http://viblend.com/products/net/wpf/controls/free-wpf-controls.aspx

That looks like this:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource Office2010SilverListBoxStyle}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource Office2010SilverListBoxItemStyle}" Content="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

But if I am clicking on an item it gets not marked as selected item.
If i am using no datatemplate all works fine. So does anyone has any idea why?
Here the working example:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" Style="{StaticResource Office2010SilverListBoxStyle}">
    <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource Office2010SilverListBoxItemStyle}">1. Frame</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource Office2010SilverListBoxItemStyle}">2. Frame</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource Office2010SilverListBoxItemStyle}">3. Frame</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource Office2010SilverListBoxItemStyle}">4. Frame</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource Office2010SilverListBoxItemStyle}">5. Frame</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Style="{StaticResource Office2010SilverListBoxItemStyle}">6. Frame</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DataTemplate` should *not* contain a `ListBoxItem`, that will be created by the `ListBox` control already, in your example there will be a `ListBoxItem` in a `ListBoxItem`, confuses selection.

Also you should apply the style to the items via `ItemContainerStyle`. (As far as i know this only works for auto-generated `ListBoxItems` which are created if you add data either directly or via `ItemsSource`, if you add `ListBoxItems` directly both `DataTemplate` and the `ItemContainerStyle` will be ignored)

See also: [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)